# precision decimal

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

**Hello
I use odoo V8 on windows 7
I would like to add a decimal precision on the print state, for example 20000.0 to 20,000.00.
I tried everything but I did not succeed
attached my code:**

```
 ## -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import time
from openerp.report import report_sxw
from openerp.osv import osv
from openerp import pooler
import locale

class etat104(report_sxw.rml_parse):
   def __init__(self, cr, uid, name, context=None):
        super(etat104, self).__init__(cr, uid, name, context=context)
        self.localcontext.update({
            'time': time,
            '_get_etat': self._get_etat,
            '_get_year': self._get_year,
            '_cpt': self._cpt
        })

   def _cpt(self, ss):
     locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'fr_FR.UTF-8')
     if ss < 0.0 :
       cpt = (locale.format('%.2f', ss, True)) 
       cpt = '(' + cpt + ')'
     else:
       cpt = (locale.format('%.2f', ss, True)) 
     return cpt

   def _get_year(self,form):
        return self.pool.get('account.fiscalyear').browse(self.cr, self.uid, form).name

   def _get_etat(self,form):
        nbr = 0 
        fiscalyear = self.pool.get('account.fiscalyear').browse(self.cr, self.uid, form['fiscalyear_id'])
        period_ids=self.pool.get('account.period').search(self.cr, self.uid, [('fiscalyear_id', '=', form['fiscalyear_id'])])

        if period_ids:
            self.cr.execute("SELECT MIN(date_start) AS date_start, MAX(date_stop) AS date_stop FROM account_period WHERE id = ANY(%s)", (period_ids,))
            dates = self.cr.dictfetchall()
        else:
            dates = False
        if dates:
            if form['tri']==False :
              query = "SELECT ai.partner_id as partner, SUM(aml.credit-aml.debit) as ht   FROM account_invoice ai, account_move am,account_move_line aml, account_account aa where ai.state IN ('open','paid') "\
                "AND ai.date_invoice >= '%s' AND ai.date_invoice <= '%s' AND ai.move_id=aml.move_id "\
                "AND ai.move_id=am.id AND aml.account_id=aa.id AND aa.code like '%s' AND aa.code not like '%s' "\
                "AND ai.type like '%s' GROUP BY partner" % (dates[0]['date_start'], dates[0]['date_stop'],'70%','706%','out_%')
            else:
              query = "SELECT ai.partner_id as partner,p.name as nom, SUM(aml.credit-aml.debit) as ht   FROM account_invoice ai, account_move am,account_move_line aml, account_account aa, res_partner p where ai.state IN ('open','paid') "\
                "AND ai.date_invoice >= '%s' AND ai.date_invoice <= '%s' AND ai.move_id=aml.move_id AND p.id=ai.partner_id "\
                "AND ai.move_id=am.id AND aml.account_id=aa.id AND aa.code like '%s' AND aa.code not like '%s' "\
                "AND ai.type like '%s' GROUP BY partner,nom ORDER BY nom" % (dates[0]['date_start'], dates[0]['date_stop'],'70%','706%','out_%')
            
            res=[]
            self.cr.execute(query)
            datas = self.cr.dictfetchall()
            obj_partner=self.pool.get('res.partner')
            ref = ''
            tht = ttax = 0.0
            for dd in datas:
              if dd['ht']==0.0:
                continue
              query="SELECT ai.partner_id as partner, SUM(aml.credit-aml.debit) as tax   FROM account_invoice ai, account_move am,account_move_line aml, account_account aa where ai.state IN ('open','paid') "\
                "AND ai.date_invoice >= '%s' AND ai.date_invoice <= '%s' and ai.move_id=aml.move_id "\
                "and ai.move_id=am.id and aml.account_id=aa.id and aa.code = '445700' "\
                "AND ai.type like '%s' AND ai.partner_id= '%s'  GROUP BY partner"  % (dates[0]['date_start'], dates[0]['date_stop'],'out_%',dd['partner'])
              # raise Warning(query)
              self.cr.execute(query)
              datas2=self.cr.dictfetchall()
              tax=0.0
              # raise Warning(query)
              for i in datas2:
                tax=i['tax']
                # raise Warning(query)
              ttax+=tax
              partner = obj_partner.read(self.cr, self.uid, dd['partner'], [])
              ref = partner['name']
              if form['reference'] == True:
                 if partner['ref'] :
                    ref= '[' + partner['ref'] + '] ' + partner['name']
                 else:    
                    ref = partner['name']
              p1=partner['street'] and partner['street'] or ''
              p2=partner['city'] and partner['city'] or ''
              rue = p1 +' '+ p2
              tht += dd['ht']
              nbr += 1
              dicts={
                    'nbr': nbr,
                    'art' : partner['ai'],
                    'rc'  : partner['rc'],
                    'nif' : partner['nif'],                    
                    'name': ref[0:20],
                    'rue' : rue[0:27],
                    'ht'  : dd['ht'],
                    'tax' : tax,
                    'tht': tht,
                    'ttax': ttax
                     }
              res.append(dicts)

                   
            return res
   ###############################################################
 
report_sxw.report_sxw('report.l10n.dz.Etat-104', 'account.move.line', 'addons/l10n_dz_report/report/rmls/etat104.rml', parser=etat104, header=False)


# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

**please help**

Answer (score 0):

You can use [formatLang](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/8.0/openerp/report/report_sxw.py#L201).

**Examples:**

*RML:*

```
formatLang(amount, digits=2, grouping=True)
```

*Parser:*

```
rml_parser = report_sxw.rml_parse(cr, uid, report_name, context=context)
rml_parser.formatLang(amount, dp='Account', currency_obj=currency)
```

In the report parser, you can simply use:

```
self.formatLang(tht)
```

***Edit:***

You can add a condition to the expression to show an empty string when the value is equal to zero.

```
[[ k.debit and formatLang(k.debit, digits=2, grouping=True) or '' ]]
```

You can find more examples in the OCA [account_financial_report](https://github.com/OCA/account-financial-reporting/blob/a80af4f474bed658478d53cf804fc34f7c998ccf/account_financial_report/report/balance_full_4_cols_journal_ledger.rml#L373) module.

Comment: thank you for your reply .
but I don't understand where I put the second code "Parser"

Comment: You can convert the amount when you initialize ``dicts``

Comment: NO !!! you can explain with more details step by step I'm new thank you

Comment: You can format the amount in the RML file using `formatLang`. Loop over `_get_etat` result and use the ``formatLang`` function to format amounts, for example `<para style="P12">[[ formatLang(d['tht']) ]]</para>`

Comment: so I have to do it line by line of the RML file because there are many different amounts

Comment: You need to do it individually for each amount.

Comment: I am looking for a solution to format the amounts of the whole file automatically

Comment: Did you try to call the format function when you declare `dicts`?

Comment: i don't know how to do this T_T

Comment: Instead of passing the `tht` as a float, format it and pass it as a string (`'tht': self.formatLang(tht),`).

Comment: I have tenes of amounts I cannot do them individually I know that a code must be changed in the py file

Comment: I can see only 4 amounts used in the `_get_etat ` function, so you have to convert those amounts and keep your report unchanged.

Comment: where are you seeing it
I change them in the py or RML file
sorry I ask a lot of stupid questions

Comment: No problem. You can find many examples in Odoo source code doing both of them, but I personally prefer to format amounts in the RML file.

Comment: you could take a look in the RML file and tell me exactly where I put the code
https://www.4shared.com/file/iK-2eNfniq/bilan_report.html

Comment: This is a different report. After a quick look, I think you need to use the format function on all  those variables in the RML file. You can't format them at once because your variables are used later to compute totals but if you compute the total in the parser you can use the format function when you set the variable in the context.

Comment: I have formatted all the amounts individually but I want that when the amount is zero the box remains empty not 0.00 !!! is it possible to do that?
my py file : https://www.4shared.com/file/e3CXOoegiq/bilan_report.html

Comment: You need to add a condition to the expression. Check my edit

Comment: thnk you for your help <3